# how to redirect to a page from javaScript after filling all the form fields

Tags: javascript, html, single-page-application

I m working with single page application and I want to redirect to a new page using javascript, after filling all the form fields and submitting.

signup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validatation() {
            debugger
            if ($("#txtfname").val() == "") {
                debugger
                alert("Provide a first name");
                $("#txtfname").focus();
                return false;
            }
            if ($("#txtmname").val() == "") {
                debugger
                alert("Provide a middle name");
                $("#txtmname").focus();
                return false;
            }
            if ($("#txtlname").val() == "") {
                debugger
                alert("Provide a last name");
                $("#txtlname").focus();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    </script>
    <script src="signup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="txtPersonalInformation" onsubmit="return validatation()">
        <h1>Personal Information</h1>

        <label for="txtfname">First Name:</label>
        <input id="txtfname" name="txtfname" type="text" /><br />

        <label for="txtmname">Middle Name:</label>
        <input id="txtmname" name="txtmname" type="text" /><br />

        <label for="txtlname">Last Name:</label>
        <input id="txtlname" name="txtlname" type="text" /><br />

        <input id="btnnext" type="submit" value="Next" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

signup.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnnext').click(function (event) {
        sessionStorage.clear();
        sessionStorage.setItem("firstName", $("#txtfname").val());
        sessionStorage.setItem("lastName", $("#txtlname").val());
        sessionStorage.setItem("middleName", $("#txtmname").val());
        $("#txtPersonalInformation").load("ContactInformation.html");
    });
});
```

ContactInformation.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="ContactInformation.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="txtContactInformation">
        <h1>Contact Information</h1>

        <label for="txtemailid">EmailAddress:</label>
        <input id="txtemailid" name="txtemailid" type="text" /><br />

        <label for="txtpass">Password:</label>
        <input id="txtpass" name="txtpass" type="password" /><br />

        <label for="txtcontactno">Contact No:</label>
        <input id="txtcontactno" name="txtcontactno" type="number" /><br />

        <input id="btnsubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

now facing below issue

when I fill only one input field and press next button, It is getting redirected to the next page

when I filled all the input field and press the next button, redirection doesn't works.

Comment: Can you add your HTML please?

Looks like the  $('#btnnext').click(function (event) { ...} function doesnt care about your validation and will just load the 'ContactInformation.html' page everytime you click the btnnext button...

Comment: where is the #txtPersonalInformation element?

Comment: clientside validation is insecure, do it on the server

Comment: @user120242 I add the #txtPersonalInformation element I edited my question

Comment: @Harry I add the html content I edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But your validation is not doing anything to prevent the next page loading.  Also, is there a reason you need to use onsubmit=?
As an SPA, to prevent navigation to the submit URL, your onsubmit function should always be calling event.preventDefault() (or return false) to prevent the default "submit" behavior of the form.

```
$('#btnnext').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if( !validatation() ) return;
    sessionStorage.clear();
    sessionStorage.setItem("firstName", $("#txtfname").val());
    sessionStorage.setItem("lastName", $("#txtlname").val());
    sessionStorage.setItem("middleName", $("#txtmname").val());
    $("#txtPersonalInformation").load("ContactInformation.html");
});
```

Comment: working your code thanks and  I searching this line but not understanding this line ```event.preventDefault();``` still i m finding which purpose of this line  can u discribe some word so I understood this line?

Comment: As the name suggests, tells the event to prevent the default action.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with you signup code(change the last line).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnnext').click(function (event) {
        sessionStorage.clear();
        sessionStorage.setItem("firstName", $("#txtfname").val());
        sessionStorage.setItem("lastName", $("#txtlname").val());
        sessionStorage.setItem("middleName", $("#txtmname").val());
        document.body.innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="ContactInformation.html" ></object>';
    });
});
```